# Cocoa MySQL Framework pointers and/or advice?

Tags: mysql, cocoa, xcode, frameworks

Hey, I'm looking to find a good MySQL framework for Cocoa that I can use in my XCode projects to access a database on the web.  Do you know of any good, open source/free ones? I have looked at http:// mysql-cocoa.sourceforge .net/index.html but haven't had a chance to play with it.  Should I start there or is there something better?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost answered your own question! Take a look at [MySQL-Cocoa](http://mysql-cocoa.sourceforge.net/).

I've had a good experience wrapping simple queries in NSOperation objects for easy multi-threading.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

MySQL Framework for iPhone :

http://www.eval-art.com/2009/06/22/mysqlframework-for-iphone/